# How to create a custom content-type with template for an "empty" page

Tags: 7, theming

I want to display a Unity webplayer in a modal/overlay. I figured out a way to show a drupal page with the webplayer in the overlay, so I'm almost there. But that page then displays everything, including menus etc. The Context module allows me to strip most of it, but not everything. So it seems having an empty page to start with will be easiest.

What would be the best way to create a Drupal page that only shows the content and is otherwise empty? I have already created a custom content-type for the webplayer, so maybe there is a way to associate that with a custom template file that only prints the content? I'm also writing a module for this, so the solution can require changes that need to be implemented in code.

I'm not very familiar with theming, so I'm also interested what template file needs to be created or changed (page.tpl.php, node.tpl.php or something else altogether).

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "only show content".  Do you want the header/footer? a blank screen?  Also "webplayer in a Drupal Overlay"  are you referring to an administrative overlay form?

Comment: I need a blank screen without headers, footers menus etc. The solution by karthik will work as I can then only output the needed javascript with the Unity object. I'm going to use Lightbox2 to display this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By code, if you want a page that display's only content, here's how I would do it.

```
function module_menu() {
$items['overlay/location']=array(
 'title' => 'Title of page',
 'page callback' => 'module_callback',
 );

return $items;
}

function module_callback() {
 echo 'show what ever!';
 //no return!
}
```

Take a look at [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/7/hook_menu)

Comment: Indeed, I was making it more complicated then necessary. This will work fine, thanks. Still, if anyone knows how to tie a specific template.tpl.php to a content-type I'm interested ;-)